# $A\times B \cong B\times A$ in a category $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, natural-transformations

*I work in a category $\mathbb{C}$, and use definitions and notation from the book '[Category Theory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2047855.Category_Theory)', by Steve Awodey.*

I'm learning some basic category theory from Awodey's book as part of self studying commutative algebra. So, I'm very new at this. In trying to understand naturality, I tried to see the simple and "natural" isomorphism between $A\times B$ and $B\times A$. I reason as follows:

Given the two products, $A\times B$ and $B\times A$, they already come equipped with arrows $p_1:A\times B\to A$, $p_2:A\times B \to B$ and $\pi_1:B\times A\to B$, $\pi_2:B\times A\to A$ respectively by definition of product.

Letting $Y=A\times B$ in the [definition of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) gives us the arrow $u_1=\langle p_2,p_1\rangle:A\times B\to B\times A$, and similarly $Y=B\times A$, gives us the arrow $u_2=\langle\pi_2,\pi_1\rangle:B\times A\to A\times B$.

By commutativity of the triangles: right including $u_2$; left including $u_2$; left including $u_1$ and right including $u_2$, in the diagram below, we get respectively:

\begin{gather*}
p_1\circ u_2=\pi_2,\quad p_2\circ u_2=\pi_1,\quad \pi_1\circ u_1=p_2,\quad \pi_2\circ u_1=p_1 \Rightarrow \\
\pi_2\circ (u_1\circ u_2)=\pi_2,\quad \pi_1\circ (u_1\circ u_2)=\pi_1,\quad p_2\circ (u_2\circ u_1)=p_2,\quad p_1\circ(u_2\circ u_1)=p_1.
\end{gather*}
Hopefully showing that $u_2\circ u_1=Id_{A\times B}$ and $u_1\circ u_2=Id_{B\times A}$.

I guess I'm using that identities for an object in $\mathbb{C}$ are unique, and thus we would only really need $\pi_1\circ (u_1\circ u_2)=\pi_1$, and $p_1\circ(u_2\circ u_1)=p_1$, to show this; Similar to showing an element is the identity in a group.

**Question(s) 1:** Is the proof/argument just given, that $A\times B\cong B\times A$, correct; If not, how can I correct it?

**Question 2:** Would this also show that the products, seen as functors (I guess provided that $\mathbb{C}$ has products) are isomorphic, or is this where naturality comes in, and we actually need to find the natural transformation between the functors?

[image: Diagram 1]

Comment: No you're not using that identities are unique, you're using the uniqueness part of the definition of product. As for Question 2, the morphism you get is actually a natural transformation, though you would have to prove it

Comment: @Max : Ok, perhaps, I was just a bit unsure there, since isn't it true that e.g. the arrow $u_1$ is unique for a given object (in this case $A\times B$) and two arrows (in this case $p_1, p_2$) into $A$ and $B$? Couldn't we thus have many arrows into $A$, and $B$ from this object, thus giving us a new arrow $u_3$, unique for say $A\times B$ and arrows $q_1, q_2$? Similarly showing something like $q_1\circ (u_2\circ u_3)=q_1$. But, if we know identities are unique, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is true that $u_1$ is unique. This uniqueness follows from $\pi_i\circ u_1=p_{2-i}$ for $i=1,2$. At most one arrow can satisfy these equalities. This because $(\pi_1,\pi_2)$ is a so-called **mono-source** (this because it is a projection pair). Also $(p_1,p_2)$ is a monosource so that there is only one arrow that satisfies $p_i\circ f=p_i$ for $i=1,2$. This arrow is of course the identity, but you proved that also $u_2\circ u_1$ has this property. Conclusion: $u_2\circ u_1$ **is** the identity. Similarly we find that $u_1\circ u_2$ is the identity. Conclusion: $u_1,u_2$ are isomorphisms.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand\C{\mathscr C}$To answer **Question 2** if you know *adjoint functors:* Let consider the following functors:
\begin{align}
\text{diagonal functor}&&\Delta&:\C\to\C\times\C&X&\mapsto (X,X)\\
\text{switch functor}&&\Sigma&:\C\times\C\to\C\times\C&(X,Y)&\mapsto(Y,X)\\
\text{product functor}&&\Pi&:\C\times\C\to\C&(X,Y)&\mapsto X\times Y
\end{align}
You are looking for a natural isomorphism $\zeta:\Pi\to\Pi\circ\Sigma$.

First note that $\Sigma$ is an isomorphism of categories since $\Sigma\circ\Sigma$ is the identity functor.
Now recall that $\Pi$ is characterized, up to natural isomorphisms, to be the right adjoint of $\Delta$, that's $\Delta\dashv\Pi$.
Then $\Sigma\circ\Delta\dashv\Pi\circ\Sigma$, but $\Sigma\circ\Delta=\Delta$, hence $\Delta\dashv\Pi\circ\Sigma$, from which $\Pi\cong\Pi\circ\Sigma$.

Comment: I do not (know _adjoint functors_), but this will come in great handy when I do. Also, it sort of make sense to me anyway.

Comment: @Christopher.L I suggest that, rather than waiting until you learn about adjoint functors to apply this answer, you prove directly that what you've constructed is a natural isomorphism. It's a bit more work than quoting theorems about adjoints, but it will help you understand what's actually happening amid all the abstractions (and help you appreciate the abstractions).

Comment: @AndreasBlass : I am actually reading on about natural transformations as we write, so I will definitely get back to it. Any hints or aid about that approach in a possible answer would be much appreciated.