# Prove that $A \oplus B \simeq B \oplus A$ using natural transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum, functors

I have to prove that  $A \oplus B \simeq  B \oplus A$ where $A,B$ are $R-$ Modules using natural transformation. I defined $\varphi: f \to g$, where $f,g$ are functors of two variables. I defined $f(A,B)= A \oplus B$ and $g(A,B)= B \oplus A$, but I don't know how to prove that $\varphi$ is an equivalence

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is wanted, but usually one would use things denoted $\pi_1,\pi_2$ and $\langle f,g \rangle$, part of the structure of $A \oplus B$ as a product (this can be equally well done with the coproduct structure as well). What notation do you use for these things?

Comment: You can prove that $A \sqcup B \approx B \sqcup A$ in any category. Not just the category of $R-$modules.

Comment: Can you give an idea?

Comment: You may be interestes to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3152787) answer to a similar question.